# .NET and P2P - writing a P2P messenger

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, p2p

Does anyone have any advice how to write such app? Or maybe knows some nice tutorial? I would like to use System.Net.PeerToPeer namespace, but everything I can find about it is MSDN which I can't read without getting mad. Or maybe using "old-school" TCP/IP would more efficient?

I will appreciate every piece of advice. Every sample code I will shower with gold ;)

And please, don't send me back to Google for I have searched for a long time for sth useful - maybe inaccurately but time is running out and I really need some help.

[edit]
What about the [Brunet library](http://boykin.acis.ufl.edu/wiki/index.php/Brunet)? Has anyone used it?

Comment: Perhaps you can link us to the articles that make you mad? Some people may possibly attempt to answer your question from scratch - at least give them a head-start.

Comment: Ok, I'll look them up when I get home.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a sample at MSDN that you may find interesting: [Peer Channel Chat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms751502.aspx).

Quote from the page:

> The Chat sample demonstrates how to
>   implement a multiparty chat
>   application by using Peer Channel.
>   Messages sent by any instance of a
>   chat application are received by all
>   other instances.
>
> The Chat sample is not based on the
>   concept of client and service. It is a
>   true peer-to-peer application with
>   each instance acting as a peer of
>   other instances. Each instance can
>   send messages to other instances and
>   receive messages from other instances
>   using the IChat duplex contract.