# Stun and P2P communication in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

I'm new to network programming. I want to traverse NAT using Stun. I use the Stun client application defined in code project [Stun Client](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/STUN_client.aspx). It returned me a mapped IP and port. But I don't know how to use the IP and port for P2P communication in C#.NET.
Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for some general background to get you started, look at this related question:

- [.NET and P2P - writing a P2P messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496080/net-and-p2p-writing-a-p2p-messenger)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
By reading the above link, it uses the PNRP for communication.and PNRP not works with symmetric NAT and the PeerCollabration is not works with windows XP. Users are behind different NATs and i want video conferencing between them.For text chat i used the jabber server. I want a solution like libjingle used by google.which works everywhere (even with symmetric NAT). Any help will appriciable

Answer (score 0):

HI all

we found that, we can traverse NAT using  vs2010 (.net4.0) . there is a method AllowNATTraversal(bool value). set the value true for NAT Traverse. It uses Ipv6 adsdress for connectivity. You can get Ipv6 global address from teredo server by writing some comands in command  prompt.