# C# - identify computer on another network

Tags: c#, networking, ip-address

i'm making a game with peer to peer connection. The thing is, local IP address works only within same network, and every computers in the network use the same public IP Address. 
Is there any other way to identify a computer on another network in C#? Maybe combination of both?

Comment: Browser or desktop game?

Comment: @TomTom Desktop game

Comment: So what is your problem? you have access toe the machine. SID, HD numbers, internal IP address, MAC addressses, processor serial number, can generate a key file on installation. Choose what you prefer and program it.

Comment: @TomTom From library I use, I can only use IP Address and Port to connect to the computer.

Comment: If you use a tool UNSUITABLE FOR THE JOB, then replace the tool.

Comment: @TomTom Then, how do they normally do peer to peer connection with another network?

Comment: You need some sort of server involvement here. This is not easy, you need to look into things like SIP, STUN and WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Peer Channel system supplied as part of WCF:

- [.NET and P2P - writing a P2P messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496080/net-and-p2p-writing-a-p2p-messenger)